# Axios get request resolving after, therefore my variable doesnt get assigned

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, axios

On my user controller , i want to send a get request to receive a json response.

When the response comes i want to assign the value to a variable calles embed, however the rendering part:

```
  res.render('user', {
    user,
    title: user.name,
    embed: embed.html,
  });
```

Happens before the axis function is finished... leaving me with an empty object.

What do i have to do in order to wait for the response... and then render the template?

Note that console log 2 happens before console log 1 in this code:

```
exports.getUserBySlug = async (req, res, next) => {

  const user = await User.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug })
  let embed = {}
  if (!user) return next();

  axios.get(`https://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=json&url=${user.musicLink}`)
  .then(response => {
    embed = response.data
  console.log('1: ', embed)

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })

  console.log('2: ', embed)

  res.render('user', {
    user,
    title: user.name,
    embed: embed.html,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request is asynchronous. You need to add one `await` more

```
exports.getUserBySlug = async (req, res, next) => {

  const user = await User.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug })
  let embed = {}
  if (!user) return next();

  await axios.get(`https://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=json&url=${user.musicLink}`)
  .then(response => {
    embed = response.data
  console.log('1: ', embed)

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })

  console.log('2: ', embed)

  res.render('user', {
    user,
    title: user.name,
    embed: embed.html,
  });
};
```

Also I would recommend NOT to mix `async/await` with `.then` calls.

```
exports.getUserBySlug = async (req, res, next) => {

  const user = await User.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug })
  let embed = {}
  if (!user) return next();

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=json&url=${user.musicLink}`)
    embed = response.data
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }

  res.render('user', {
    user,
    title: user.name,
    embed: embed.html,
  });
};
```